# How to read, write and update of your game highscore in pygame from/to file.txt saved.?

Tags: python-3.x

I am beginner who just copy a game sample from a book. The game working fine, and i able to understand all part of the exclude the read, write part.
The book didn't explain how it work and i been stuck at this part.
p/s: the game work totally fine. Just unable to write and read from highscore list.

```
def update_high_scores():
global score, scores
filename = r"/Users/User/Desktop/python/python-games/baloon fight/High-Score1.txt"
scores = []
with open(filename, "r") as file:
    line = file.readline()
    high_scores = line.split()
for high_score in high_scores:
    if(score > int(high_score)):
        scores.append(str(score) + " ")
        score = int(high_score)
    else:
        scores.append(str(high_score) + " ")

with open(filename, "w") as file:
    for high_score in scores:
        file.write(high_score)
        
def display_high_scores(): 
screen.draw.text("HIGH SCORES", (350, 150), color="black")
y = 175
position = 1
for high_score in scores:
    screen.draw.text(str(position) + ". " + high_score, (350, y), color="black")
    y += 25
    position += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with your code, but updating it made the code more complicated. I thought it may be easier to provide a short function to update the score file.

The main steps:

- Open the existing score file (scores are on single line separated by space)
- Split the line and convert the scores to integers
- If the current score is already included, just exit the function
- Add the current score the score list
- Sort the list and update the score file

Here is the code:

```
def update_high_scores():
    global score, scores
    filename = r"c:/tmp/High-Score1.txt"  # file must exist
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        line = file.readline()  # scores are one line
        high_scores = [int(s) for s in line.split()]  # read scores as integers
    if score in high_scores:  # if current score already in high scores
        return # no update needed

    high_scores.append(score)  # add current score

    high_scores.sort()  # sort scores  (low - high)

    with open(filename, "w") as file:  # updates score file
        for high_score in high_scores[::-1]:  # write scores in reverse (high - low)
            file.write(str(high_score) + " ")
```